# How to install Python in iOS9?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, jailbreak

I want to install Python on my iPhone6, then i install it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/yangapp/downloads/detail?name=python_2.7.2-5_iphoneos-arm.deb&can=2&q=), but i failed when i access python with `python` in MTerminal, the error is

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/bin/python
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x0024D000, size=0x00029000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
>           /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x00435000, size=0x00029000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
>   Trace/BPT trap: 5

and what should i do to continue?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an iOS 9 compatible python 2.7 package [here.](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!APbsHsgWQMnaVVM&cid=AB142AFF051B6CD3&id=AB142AFF051B6CD3!16995&parId=AB142AFF051B6CD3!102&action=locate)
It comes with most of the base modules and works fairly well. I did however run into two problems.

- **Easy_install does not work.** This did work on older packages and makes it difficult to install other modules. The problem is that no iOS 9 compatible `zlib` library(required by easy_install) has not been ported yet.
- **Certain base modules are missing or parts are not working.** The most used modules are there like `OS` and `sys`. One of the missing modules is the `time` module. Also, the `os.environ` returns an empty dictionary.

So, if you just want the base python for simple scripts, it works. But for other, more complex programs that require extra modules, you will probably run into lots of errors.